# Access problem (?) Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: software, equipment-troubleshooting, linux, wsjt-x

Radio: FT-991

I work usually in Mint 20.3 Mate;
FLRig, FLDigi, JS8, JTDX, WSJTX all run ufb

Installed a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (on another Laptop)
Now:

- FLRig, FLDigi: after setting permission / Owner - Runs
- JS8: (FLRig connected) - Runs
- **WSJTX: (FLRig connected) - (FLRig connected) - PTT ok and set same sound device - no output
- JTDX: (FLRig connected) - PTT ok and set same sound device - no output**

How do I solve this?

Comment: You've verified that the sound device works for other apps (like a browser or mp3 player?)

Comment: Hey there @HB9FIH.  Would you mind taking a pass at editing that for readability and clarity?  I started doing it myself, but I think it really needs the OP's touch here.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer yeah, I had to go in and reformat it so I could read it myself, so I said, might as well edit the question for all. But I 100% agree: HB9FIH: I did my best, but I don't think I've really "fixed" your question. Please overhaul my edit, and make sure your intention comes clearly across.

Comment: TNX for the answers - 
The sound system obviously is ok in the PC.
The second soundcard (in the USB Interface to the radio) is recognized and working.
Two programms are exchanging he sound input/output well (FLDIGI / JS8 Call)
... The other two programms (WSJTX, JTDX) receive only the sound from radio.
My Question is: is it possible because of permissions that sending sound from these two programms are blocked ?  
Configuration in the radio are the same as in the working Mint system.

Comment: Are you running these programs simultaneously?

Comment: No each program run once and exclusive (its not possible also bc of radio and antennas - and stress if some owns such equipment ;-))

Comment: I had similar issue with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS that went away with Non-Gnome desktop. I forgot what it was but GNOME uses another layer of audio management that can interfere with the audio sinks. Try another desktop environment to check this. I think you want to check the GDM's auto spawn feature. Turn that off.

Comment: To add to what @wbg said, I run xubuntu 20.04 (which uses xcfe) and have no trouble.